# How can I exclude a certain class from inheriting property in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have circular logo here as you can see , I'm trying to have my circle logo and "name" and "family" around it , like : "name" logo "family" and I want to exclude "container" from being flex child because I want to align them left not center here's my codes:

```css
header {
  width: auto;
  height: 35vh;
  background-color: var(--clr-accent);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logo {
  background: url(/src/logo.png);
  width: 6rem;
  height: 6rem;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 3rem 3rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.name-fam {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="name-fam">
    <h2>Name</h2>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <h2>Family</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <h4>My marital status:</h4>
      <div class="marital-status"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4>my birthday:</h4>
      <div class="birthday-date"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

note: I want flexbox inside my container (it's children) but exclude container itself from being flex element and being centralized.

Comment: Why don't you remove `display: flex` from your `header` if you don't want your `.container` to be flex child? What layout are you trying to achieve? That would probably help us more in assisting you.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense: The only other flex items that would remain is `personal-info`, which as only item would be centered due to  `justify-content:center` inside  `header` (and you also want to center `container`... -?? )

Comment: @disinfor I have logo and I want my name and family around it , like "name logo family" and under of it I want some information aligned left . whole code is too long to send

Comment: @gvdltubdlpwfsgmpx it appears your HTML markup won't work with what you want.

Comment: You're asking an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). Instead, revise to ask about your actual problem.

Comment: Fine, but you haven't updated your _question_.

Comment: @disinfor i did it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `display: flex` on your header, since you can use `margin: 0 auto` on the `name-fam` div. Also, not sure why `row-reverse` was used on `nam-fam` since the elements are in the order you wanted in the markup.

```css
header {
  width: auto;
  height: 35vh;
  background-color: var(--clr-accent);
}

.logo {
  background: url(/src/logo.png);
  width: 6rem;
  height: 6rem;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 3rem 3rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.name-fam {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="name-fam">
    <h2>Name</h2>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <h2>Family</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <h4>My marital status:</h4>
      <div class="marital-status"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4>my birthday:</h4>
      <div class="birthday-date"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

If you want to keep `display: flex` on the `header`

```css
header {
  width: auto;
  height: 35vh;
  background-color: var(--clr-accent);
  display: flex;
  /* Change to row */
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logo {
  background: url(/src/logo.png);
  width: 6rem;
  height: 6rem;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 3rem 3rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.name-fam {
  display: flex;
}

/* Add this to container to make sure it's 100% width so it will not appear to be centered */
.container {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="name-fam">
    <h2>Name</h2>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <h2>Family</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <h4>My marital status:</h4>
      <div class="marital-status"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4>my birthday:</h4>
      <div class="birthday-date"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```